# Logging as a cross-cutting concern in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, logfile

I would like to log to file every time my Web service is called recording the name of the method called as well as the calling data.

To write in this file, I use [Nlog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog) but I would like not to make the logging call in each of my service operations. I'd prefer to automate this logging call somehow as a cross cutting concern.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a DI container supporting interceptors to log any WCF method call with input values. Here is an example for `Ninject` and old weird ASMX service (for WCF, idea is the same):

Let's consider the following client class:

```
public partial class LegacyClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<Legacy>, Legacy
```

Because this class is partial, we may easily add to class the interface `ILegacyClient` containing methods we want to call. ReSharper extract the interface in a second. So place the partial class declaration in separate file:

```
public partial class LegacyClient : ILegacyClient {}
```

In DI config, add the interceptor:

```
Kernel.Bind(typeof(ILegacyClient))
    .To<LegacyClient>()
    .InRequestScope() //carefully choose a scope
    .Intercept()
    .With<LogRequestInterceptor>();
```

`LogRequestInterceptor` is the most interesting part:

```
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Extensions.Interception;

public class LogRequestInterceptor : IInterceptor 
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        MethodInfo method = invocation.Request.Method;

        var parameters = method.GetParameters();

        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int index = 0; index < parameters.Length; index++)
        {
            object argument = invocation.Request.Arguments[index];

            ParameterInfo parameterInfo = parameters[index];

            if (!parameterInfo.IsOut)
            {
                //use any serialization you like
                string text = $"{parameterInfo.Name} = {argument.ToJson()}, ";

                builder.Append(text);
            }
        }

        string joinedParameters = builder.ToString();

        YourLogging(method.Name, joinedParameters); 

        //LegacyClient method call, don't forget this line
        invocation.Proceed();
    }
}
```

Last part to make things work. Create proxy object via DI and use it:

```
ILegacyClient client = Kernel.GetService<ILegacyClient>();
client.AnyMethodCall(...);
```

Direct creation is only an example, of course you may use constuctor or property injection instead and replace client interface with factory if you need.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

1. You can try to use either Aspect Oriented programming (AOP) using Windsor Castle, PostSharp or other 3rd party Libraries offering AOP. Also, you may use interceptors from these Libraries.
2. WCF [Extension](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/05/16/wcf-extensibility-ioperationinvoker/) might be another place to do this kind of logging.
3. Using WCF tracing. You can view the Service calls, message level details etc by enabling WCF tracing by Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from **[Agalo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1696326/agalo)** is correct but too general, so I would just add a link to how to implement #2. I guess this is exactly what question author wants to have.

In a nutshell, you can implement your own parameter inspector (`IParameterInspector`) and inject it using service behavior (`IServiceBehavior`). [Here you can find complete example how to do that](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/243352/LoggingBehavior-How-to-Connect-Log-prints-with-the) for logging.